# How to get parent folder name from path

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to get parent name from workspaceFolder path.Example

```
 ${workspaceFolder} -  
 ${workspaceFolderBasename} - your-project
```

But How to get " your-username " name from workspaceFolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the `path` package in your extension:

```
const path = require("path");

const parentDirectory = path.basename(path.dirname(${workspaceFolder}));  // your-username
```

Comment: Can  you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443994/how-to-convert-image-to-base-64-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to get up to the 5th parent.

```
${command:extension.commandvariable.workspace.folderBasename1Up}
```